# Multiply 2 input fields on keyup?

Tags: jquery, html

I've got 2 fields

```
<input id="E_Item1" name="E_Item1">
<input id="E_CCNM" name="E_CCNM">
```

In JQuery, how would I go about multiplying the values of these fields together on keyup into a div?

Comment: http://bit.ly/RaHKy1

Comment: @ahern - lol! that's probably the best answer one could have given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input id="E_Item1" name="E_Item1" type="text" class="multiplier">
<input id="E_CCNM" name="E_CCNM" type="text" class="multiplier">
<div id="results"></div>
```

then, assuming the expected results are multiples of integers, in js you do something like this in your ready listener...

```
$('.multiplier').on('keyup', function(){
    $('#results').html("&pound;" + parseInt($('#E_Item1').val()) * parseInt($('#E_CCNM').val()));
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gygL6/ - worked for me. Yeah, you get NAN when ther eis no value in one box, but you should be able to figure out how to handle that.

Comment: Sorted :)  How would I force a currency symbol in there.  Say £?

Comment: Updated. just add the html for that symbol before the math in the .html()

Comment: Ah brilliant. Was almost there, was using . instead of +

Answer (score 0):

jQuery offers you comfortable [event listeners](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

To access the value of an input you can use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/): `$('#elementID').val()`.

Therefore, your whole code would be something like that:

```
$('#getResult').on('click', function(e){
    var val1 = $('#E_Item1').val();
    var val2 = $('#E_CCNM').val();
    alert(parseFloat(val1)*parseFloat(val2));
});​
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GymEa/))

---

Please take a look at the following links. You would have found them if you used **Google** und were able to solve the problem by yourself:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/val/